# CODE TO DISPLAY CONTENTS OF FILE IN RICHTEXTBOX

Tags: vb6

CODE TO DISPLAY CONTENTS OF FILE IN RICHTEXTBOX

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Dim contentfile As String
    On Error GoTo a
    Form5.CommonDialog1.ShowOpen
    Open Form5.CommonDialog1.FileName For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Input #1, contentfile
        Form5.RichTextBox1 = Form5.RichTextBox1 + contentfile + vbCrLf
    Loop
    Close #1
    a:
End Sub
```

Comment: please give a solution soon

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You haven't asked a question, so we can't give a solution. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and turn off caps lock when posting.

Comment: I shall take as much time on your problem as you spent composing a good question, good title and formatting your code.

Comment: `Form5.RichTextBox1.LoadFile "filenamehere"`

Comment: @Plutonix you have spent too much time already...

Comment: I don't know what the default property, (or if there even is one) of the RichTextbox is, but I'm guessing that is your problem. Pick the property (`Form5.RichTextBox1.TextRTF = Form5.RichTextBox1.TextRTF + contentfile + vbCrLf`?) you are trying to assign to and if you still have a problem let us know what isn't working. And please change the "+" to "&". `Form5.RichTextBox1.TextRTF = Form5.RichTextBox1.TextRTF & contentfile & vbCrLf`

Answer (score 1):

The help content on the RTF component can be found [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261642(v=vs.60).aspx) from MSDN. The control and its possibilities is explained as follow -

> LoadFile Method
>
> See Also    Example    Applies To
>   Loads an .rtf file or text file into a RichTextBox control.
>   Syntax
>   object.LoadFile pathname, filetype
>   The LoadFile method syntax has these parts:
>   Part    Description
>   object  Required. An object expression that evaluates to an object in the Applies To list.
>   pathname    Required. A string expression defining the path and filename of the file to load into the control.
>   filetype    Optional. An integer or constant that specifies the type of file loaded, as described in Settings.
>
> Settings
>   The settings for filetype are:
>   Constant    Value   Description
>   rtfRTF  0   (Default) RTF. The file loaded must be a valid .rtf file.
>   rtfText 1   Text. The RichTextBox control loads any text file.
>
> Remarks
>   When loading a file with the LoadFile method, the contents of the loaded file replaces the entire contents of the RichTextBox control. This will cause the values of the Text and RTFText properties to change.
>   You can also use the Input function in Visual Basic and the TextRTF and SelRTF properties of the RichTextBox control to read .rtf files. For example, you can load the contents of an .rtf file to the RichTextBox control as follows:

```
Open "mytext.rtf" For Input As 1

RichTextBox1.TextRTF = Strconv(InputB$(LOF(1), 1), vbUnicode)
```

Trust this will help.